# Fix top position of div even when div changes size and keep div centered

Tags: css

I have a div that gets taller when a user selects a certain checkbox.

The default behavior of this div was that when the checkbox is selected the div grows equally at the top and bottom. The top becomes higher and the bottom becomes lower. I would like the top of the div to be fixed and only allow the bottom to become lower so that the content of the div that is present regardless of the checkbox state does not move when the user selects or deselects the checkbox.

I found that adding this styling to the div does the trick.

```
.fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 400px;
}
```

However, this also moves the div to the left side of the page. I need it to be centered. The div should be a fixed width unless thear window is narrower than that width in which case the div should become narrower.

If I change the position attribute to relative, then the div is centered properly as described above, but the top is no longer fixed.

How can I make the top of the div fixed, while at the same time satisfying the width requirement set forth above?

Comment: Share your code in the snippet

Comment: Try to make a working example describing your problems, so everybody understands properly what problems you are facing and how o solve it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -120px;
  top: 0;
  width:240px;
}
```

Try this code....

Comment: How did this solve his problems? `margin-left: -120px` how you calculated this?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I would solve this

First, please make sure the parent element of the div have its own width (in your case, width:100%;) and have any kind of position (e.g. position: relative;) otherwise this trick wont work.

```
.fixed-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 400px;

  // add this
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

The trick is to set the div's left attribute by 50% of its parent element width, then move (translateX) it back (-50%) by half of the div width.

You can also use this trick on top attribute too.

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

or use this to center both top and left

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the div position attribute to be relative, you can use

```
.fixed-top {
  position: relative;
  // instead top, we use margin-top
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 400px;

  // add this
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Helps, but a side effect is that clicking outside of the modal
no longer closes the modal.

Comment: I think you can try adding some height attribute, maybe height: auto;
or try display: inline-block
Or maybe the second approach will do, position: relative; one